# Express new session on a request from frontend app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, session, cookies

I am creating a login page, and the problem is that express creating a new session each time a request comes from the frontend app. I have checked and tried all the other answers on the net and here at SO. The part that bugs me most is that it works with curl, but not via the frontend app. 
Here is the code:
server.js

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const session = require('express-session')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(cookieParser('keyboard cat'));
app.set('trust proxy', true);
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    httpOnly: true,
    cookie: {secure: false}
}));

app.get('/secured', function (req, res) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3006");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Cookie");
    if (req.session) {
        console.log("has session", req.session);
        if (req.session.loggedInUser) {
            res.status(200).end("OK");
        } else {
            res.status(401).end("NOTOK1");
        }
    } else {
        res.status(401).end("NOTOK2");
    }
});

const users = [
    {email: 'foo@bar.com', pass: 'foo'}
];
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    const matched = users.filter(e => e.email === req.body.loginEmail && e.pass === req.body.loginPassword);
    if (matched === undefined || matched.length === 0) {
        res.status(401).end('NOTOK');
    } else {
        req.session.loggedInUser = matched[0];
        req.session.save();
        res.status(200).end('OK');
    }
});

app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log('Started, listening');
});
```

And the login component from the frontend (React).

```
import React from "react";
import {MDBBtn, MDBCol, MDBContainer, MDBRow} from 'mdbreact';
import axios from 'axios';

class Login extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {error:{}};
        this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleLogin(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let state = this.state;
        let registerFormInputs = Object.keys(this.state).filter(v => v.startsWith("login"));
        const data = {};
        registerFormInputs.forEach(function (input) {
            data[input] = state[input];
        });
        axios.post('http://localhost:8000/login', data)
            .then(function (response) {
                axios.get('http://localhost:8000/secured', {withCredentials: true})
                    .then(resp => {
                        console.log(resp);
                    });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                this.setState({error: err.response})
            })

    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({[event.target.id]: event.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <MDBContainer>
                    <MDBRow>
                        <MDBCol md="6">
                            <form onSubmit={this.handleLogin}>
                                <p className="h4 text-center mb-4">Log in</p>
                                {this.state.error.data ? <div>{this.state.error.data}</div> : null}
                                <label htmlFor="loginEmail" className="grey-text">
                                    Email
                                </label>
                                <input
                                    type="email"
                                    id="loginEmail"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                />
                                <br/>
                                <label htmlFor="loginPassword" className="grey-text">
                                    Password
                                </label>
                                <input
                                    type="password"
                                    id="loginPassword"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                />
                                <div className="text-center mt-4">
                                    <MDBBtn color="indigo" type="submit">Login</MDBBtn>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </MDBCol>
                    </MDBRow>
                </MDBContainer>
            );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

**The frontend:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/2vor7xproj

**The backend:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/j755x416j9

Comment: Are you using `https`?

Comment: No, using http, as you can see the request that is being made.

Comment: Your browser must be blocking cookies if none of the other solutions is working. Please check to make sure cookies are enabled from localhost:8000

Answer (score 1):

I dont generally handle sessions directly. I let passportJS deal with that.
However, in the session constructor saveUninitialized is generally set to false when dealing with login events or trying to deal with race conditions in parallel requests.

From express-session npm
**saveUninitialized**
Forces a session that is "uninitialized" to be saved to the store. A session is uninitialized when it is new but not modified. Choosing false is useful for implementing login sessions, reducing server storage usage, or complying with laws that require permission before setting a cookie. Choosing false will also help with race conditions where a client makes multiple parallel requests without a session.

The default value is true, but using the default has been deprecated, as the default will change in the future. Please research into this setting and choose what is appropriate to your use-case.